# memory problems when using float4 in thrust cuda

Tags: cuda, thrust

i've encountered a memory problem when using float4 in thrust cuda

adding the float4 "buggyVariable" as a member to the functor seems to cause the float data to be get left shifted by 1 float.

in CUDA_animateParticles i clearly set Y to 0 and Z to 1

yet when running the functor and drawing it in OpenGL. I get particles with Xposition=1 which indicate that Y that is 1 inside the functor.

i've also tested with float2 and float3 they seem to work fine.

so it seems to be a memory alignment issue or a bug.

can anyone shed some light on this? thanks for the help.

```
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include "cutil_math.h"

struct animateParticles_functor
{
    float4 buggyVariable; //why does adding this variable cause following floats to get wrong values???
    float pex, pey, pez, pew;

    __host__ __device__
    animateParticles_functor( float x, float y, float z, float w) :
        pex(x), pey(y), pez(z), pew(w)
    {
    }

    template <typename Tuple>
    __host__ __device__
    void operator()(Tuple t)
    {
        if(pey > 0)
            thrust::get<0>(t) = make_float4(1, 0, 0, 0); //true if y is bugged
        else
            thrust::get<0>(t) = make_float4(0, 0, 0, 0); //false if its not bugged

        return;
    }
}

void CUDA_animateParticles(float4* cuda_devicePointer_vboPosition, float3* cuda_devicePointer_particleVelocitys, unsigned int numParticles, float4 particleEmitter)
{
    thrust::device_ptr<float4> d_pos(cuda_devicePointer_vboPosition);
    thrust::device_ptr<float3> d_vel(cuda_devicePointer_particleVelocitys);

    thrust::for_each(
        thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_pos, d_vel)),
        thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_pos + numParticles, d_vel + numParticles)),
        animateParticles_functor(0, 0, 1, 0) //notice that i set Z to 1 and not Y to 0
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are some flavors of MSVC where `nvcc` and `cl.exe` can't agree on `sizeof(float4)`.

Try replacing your use of `float4` with `my_float4`:

```
struct my_float4
{
  float x, y, z, w;
};
```

Comment: isn't the size of a float4 obvious no matter what compiler you use?

Comment: Alignment complicates things.